# Can't do a commit to my PostgreSQL database with Java

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a problem with PostgreSQL and Java. I can not do a commit to my database. This is my source code of the method I wrote:

```
@Override
    public void addToTable(T t, int i) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            int id = this.getId(t.getName());
            String sql = "INSERT INTO app.my_table_name VALUES (\'" +
                    i + "\', \'" + id + "\');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            stmt.close();
            c.commit();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage());
            for (StackTraceElement error : e.getStackTrace()) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");
    }
```

**I only got the feedback from console:**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
```

**So I didn't get so much information of that so I tried get out the Stack Trace, but that didn't gave me so much either:**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:865)
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.commit(PgConnection.java:851)
main.PostgreSQL.addToTable(PostgreSQL.java:87)
main.scene.Table.lambda$setInitialData$1(Table.java:90)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**The Stack Trace points to this line that is the problem:**

```
c.commit();
```

Why is this problem occuring? I have no other problems doing an insert operation to my database with almost identical code. I have tried getting output of `int id = this.getId(t.getName());` and it gives output of what is desired. The same with the `int i` as the parameter.

**EDIT:**

**My complete Class file:**

```
package main;

import main.model.Drink;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;

public class PostgreSQL implements IDatabase {
    private Connection c;
    private Statement stmt;
    private final String connectionUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db";
    private final String connectionUser = "postgres";
    private final String connectionPwd = "test1234";

    public PostgreSQL() {
        c = null;
        stmt = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void addTable(String tableName) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO app.tables VALUES (DEFAULT, \'" + tableName + "\');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            c.commit();

            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");
    }

    @Override
    public void addDrink(Double price, String name, String category) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO app.drinks VALUES (DEFAULT, \'" +
                    price + "\', \'" + name + "\', \'" + category + "\');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            c.commit();

            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");
    }

    @Override
    public void addDrinkToTable(Drink drink, int tableId) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            int drinkId = this.getDrinkId(drink.getName());
            String sql = "INSERT INTO app.tables_drinks VALUES (\'" +
                    tableId + "\', \'" + drinkId + "\');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            c.commit();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage());
            for (StackTraceElement error : e.getStackTrace()) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");
    }

    @Override
    public void addReceipt(String server, String date, int tableId) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            stmt = c.createStatement();

            // Creates receipt
            String sql = "INSERT INTO app.receipts VALUES (DEFAULT, " +
                    "\'" + server + "\', \'" + date + "\');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            // Gets the newly created receipt id
            Statement stmtQuery = c.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
            );

            String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM app.receipts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
            ResultSet rs = stmtQuery.executeQuery(sql2);
            rs.last();
            int receiptId = rs.getInt("id");

            // Creates row in receipts_tables with receipt id and table id
            String sql3 = "INSERT INTO app.receipts_tables VALUES (" + receiptId + ", " + tableId + ")";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql3);

            c.commit();

            stmtQuery.close();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");
    }

    @Override
    public LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> getTables() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            // Gets the newly created receipt id
            Statement stmtQuery = c.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
            );

            LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> allTables = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM app.tables;";
            ResultSet rs = stmtQuery.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                allTables.put(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("table_name"));
            }

            c.commit();

            stmtQuery.close();
            c.close();

            return allTables;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public LinkedHashMap<String, List<Drink>> getDrinks() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            // Gets the newly created receipt id
            Statement stmtQuery = c.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
            );

            LinkedHashMap<String, List<Drink>> allDrinks = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM app.drinks;";
            ResultSet rs = stmtQuery.executeQuery(sql);
            List<Drink> drinkList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Drink d = new Drink(rs.getString("drink_name"),
                        rs.getString("drink_category"),
                        rs.getDouble("drink_price")
                );
                drinkList.add(d);
            }

            allDrinks.put("allDrinks", drinkList);

            c.commit();

            stmtQuery.close();
            c.close();

            return allDrinks;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public LinkedHashMap<String, List<Drink>> getTableDrinks(int tableId) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            // Gets the newly created receipt id
            Statement stmtQuery = c.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
            );

            LinkedHashMap<String, List<Drink>> allDrinks = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            String sql = "SELECT d.drink_name, d.drink_category, d.drink_price " +
                    "FROM app.drinks d, app.tables_drinks td " +
                    "JOIN app.tables tb ON tb.id = td.table_id " +
                    "WHERE d.id = td.drink_id AND td.table_id = '" + tableId + "';";
            ResultSet rs = stmtQuery.executeQuery(sql);
            List<Drink> drinkList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Drink d = new Drink(
                        rs.getString("drink_name"),
                        rs.getString("drink_category"),
                        rs.getDouble("drink_price")
                );
                drinkList.add(d);
            }

            allDrinks.put("allDrinks", drinkList);

            c.commit();

            stmtQuery.close();
            c.close();

            return allDrinks;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTableId(String tableName) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            // Gets the newly created receipt id
            Statement stmtQuery = c.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
            );

            int tableId = 0;
            String sql = "SELECT tl.id FROM app.tables tl WHERE tl.table_name = " +
                    "'" + tableName + "'" + "LIMIT 1;";
            ResultSet rs = stmtQuery.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                tableId = rs.getInt("id");
            }

            c.commit();

            stmtQuery.close();
            c.close();

            return tableId;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDrinkId(String drinkName) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPwd);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            // Gets the newly created receipt id
            Statement stmtQuery = c.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
            );

            int tableId = 0;
            String sql = "SELECT dr.id FROM app.drinks dr WHERE dr.drink_name = " +
                    "'" + drinkName + "'" + "LIMIT 1;";
            ResultSet rs = stmtQuery.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                tableId = rs.getInt("id");
            }

            c.commit();

            stmtQuery.close();
            c.close();

            return tableId;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Row inserted successfully");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: please do **not** concatenate input like that into a SQL string (and numbers shouldn't be enclosed in single quotes anyway). Learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Little Bobby Tables...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Please share optimal solution for that. I'm a little rusty on Java. I did not like writing that way.

Comment: https://mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Answer (score 0):

It is really depending on the context you are trying to use that code.

If is directly inside a basic Java project, maybe it could run. I have not looking long on your code so I can not guarantee you about any mistake you have done.

If is directly inside a web project, maybe you must add some database configuration to maintain a pooled connection with your postgresql database (or any other db providers too, in fact). Because the db connection is released before you have sent your SQL requests, so it does not work. Logical.

In some web frameworks, there are some web filters you must add insid your web.xml file in order to handle that job. At least inside spring-web-mvc applications since 2007, if I remember me well.